# subfloatrow: incorrect continued numbering

Tags: numbering, captions, subfloats, floatrow

I am using the `subfloatrow` environment (provided by the [`floatrow`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/floatrow/floatrow.pdf) package) to organise the layout of figures for my thesis. For the MWE provided below, the numbering of the sub-figures in the second figure incorrectly starts at `(c)` rather then `(a)`.

Can anyone tell me why this occurs and how best to fix it?

I haven't had this issue previously so am wondering if it is related to my usage of the `subfloatrow*` environment and `\RawCaption` in the second figure.

```
    \documentclass[a4paper]{article}

    \usepackage[margin=20mm]{geometry}
    \usepackage[sc,osf]{mathpazo}
    \usepackage{fix-cm}
    \usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}

    \usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}

    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    \usepackage{textcomp}

    \usepackage[format=plain,indention=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
    \usepackage[justification=raggedright,font=scriptsize,labelfont=]{subcaption}

    \usepackage[facing=yes,capbesideposition={inside,center}]{floatrow}
    \floatsetup[table]{style=plaintop}
    \floatsetup[subfigure]{style=plain}

    \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}    

    \begin{document}    

    \begin{figure}[ht!]
    \centering
    \ffigbox{%
    \begin{subfloatrow}[1]%
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics*[scale=1.0]{blank_figure.pdf}}{\caption{Condition A}}
    \end{subfloatrow}
    \vspace{1ex}

    \begin{subfloatrow}[1]%
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics*[scale=1.0]{blank_figure.pdf}} {\caption{Condition B}}
    \end{subfloatrow}
    }{\caption{Overall caption of first set of figures.}}
    \end{figure}    

    \begin{figure}[p]
    \vspace{-4ex}
    \ffigbox{}{
    \begin{subfloatrow*}
        \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics*[width=77mm,height=78mm]{blank_figure.pdf}}{\subcaption{Molecular Nitrogen}}
        \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics*[width=77mm,height=78mm]{blank_figure.pdf}}{\subcaption{Molecular Oxygen}}
    \end{subfloatrow*}
    \vspace{1ex}

    \begin{subfloatrow*}
        \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics*[width=77mm,height=67mm]{blank_figure.pdf}}{\subcaption{Atomic Nitrogen}}
        \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics*[width=77mm,height=67mm]{blank_figure.pdf}}{\subcaption{Atomic Oxygen}}
    \end{subfloatrow*}
    \vspace{1ex}

    \begin{subfloatrow*}
        \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics*[width=77mm,height=67mm]{blank_figure.pdf}}{\subcaption{Nitrous Oxide}}
        \ffigbox[77mm][67mm][c]{}{\RawCaption{\caption{Overall caption for second set of figures.}}}
    \end{subfloatrow*}
    }
    \end{figure}

    \end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your example document is fine when using `caption` v3.2f this is either a bug in the actual version v3.3 or an incompatibility between `caption` and `floatrow` caused by the re-implementation of the counter handling in `caption` v3.3 (which became necessary due some issues of the old counter handling). However, since `floatrow` is not supported by its author anymore I need to fix this anyway, which I will do within the next weeks.

Until then you can reset the sub-figure counter for yourself as workaround, this can be done with `\setcounter{subfigure}{0}`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[format=plain,indention=10pt,font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage[justification=raggedright,font=scriptsize,labelfont=]{subcaption}

\usepackage[facing=yes,capbesideposition={inside,center}]{floatrow}
\floatsetup[table]{style=plaintop}
\floatsetup[subfigure]{style=plain}

\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}    

\begin{document}    

\begin{figure}[ht!]
\centering
\ffigbox{%
\begin{subfloatrow}[1]%
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics*[scale=1.0]{blank_figure.pdf}}{\caption{Condition A}}
\end{subfloatrow}
\vspace{1ex}

\begin{subfloatrow}[1]%
\ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics*[scale=1.0]{blank_figure.pdf}} {\caption{Condition B}}
\end{subfloatrow}
}{\caption{Overall caption of first set of figures.}}
\end{figure}    

\begin{figure}[p]
\setcounter{subfigure}{0}% THIS LINE ADDED
\vspace{-4ex}
\ffigbox{}{
\begin{subfloatrow*}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics*[width=77mm,height=78mm]{blank_figure.pdf}}{\subcaption{Molecular Nitrogen}}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics*[width=77mm,height=78mm]{blank_figure.pdf}}{\subcaption{Molecular Oxygen}}
\end{subfloatrow*}
\vspace{1ex}

\begin{subfloatrow*}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics*[width=77mm,height=67mm]{blank_figure.pdf}}{\subcaption{Atomic Nitrogen}}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics*[width=77mm,height=67mm]{blank_figure.pdf}}{\subcaption{Atomic Oxygen}}
\end{subfloatrow*}
\vspace{1ex}

\begin{subfloatrow*}
    \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\includegraphics*[width=77mm,height=67mm]{blank_figure.pdf}}{\subcaption{Nitrous Oxide}}
    \ffigbox[77mm][67mm][c]{}{\RawCaption{\caption{Overall caption for second set of figures.}}}
\end{subfloatrow*}
}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

P.S.: https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/tickets/6/

**Addendum (2013-04-14)**

It was indeed an incompatibility between the `floatrow` package and the new counter handling of the `caption` package v3.3, which I bypass now with an extension of the corresponding macro `\FR@loc@` provided by the `floatrow` package.

I will upload a new version of the `caption` package bundle ASAP. Impatient ones can get the current version here:

https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/code/HEAD/tree/trunk/tex/

Comment: Thanks Axel. I am indeed using caption v3.3. I was reasonably sure that I could manually reset the counter but couldn't remember how. Even so I thought that I should raise this, particularly given that counters are something LaTeX usually handles so well.