# Subfloatrow: Omitted incrementation in figure numbering when using subfigures

Tags: numbering, captions, subfloats, subcaption, floatrow

I suspect this question is slighty related to another question found in [subfloatrow: incorrect continued numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/103361/3954). Trying out the MWE below, the incrementation of the figure number of figure two is omitted. That is, the caption of figures one and two both get the same number, i.e. `1` in this case, and figure three gets the number `2`. This happens every time I use subfigures with the `subfloatrow` environment, as shown below.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{format=hang,font=small,labelfont=bf,labelsep=colon}
\captionsetup[subfigure]{labelformat=parens,font=small,labelfont=bf,textfont=sl,labelsep=space,list=no}

\usepackage[subrefformat=parens]{subcaption}

\usepackage[captionskip=13pt,facing=yes]{floatrow}
\floatsetup[figure]{margins=centering}
\floatsetup[subfigure]{style=plain,margins=raggedright,heightadjust=object}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[hbtp]
    \ffigbox[\textwidth]{%
    \caption{First figure.}
    \label{figure1}}
    {\makebox{\framebox[2.5cm]{\rule{0pt}{2.5cm}}}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[hbtp]
    \ffigbox[\textwidth]{\CommonHeightRow{%
    \begin{subfloatrow}[2]\useFCwidth
        \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\subcaption{Subfigure a}\label{subfig:a}}{\makebox{\framebox[2.5cm]{\rule{0pt}{2.5cm}}}}
        \ffigbox[\FBwidth]{\subcaption{Subfigure b}\label{subfig:b}}{\makebox{\framebox[2.5cm]{\rule{0pt}{2.5cm}}}}
    \end{subfloatrow}}}{%
    \caption{Second figure with subfigure~\subref{subfig:a} and subfigure~\subref{subfig:b}.}
    \label{figure2}}
\end{figure}
\begin{figure}[hbtp]
    \ffigbox[\textwidth]{%
    \caption{Third figure.}
    \label{figure3}}
    {\makebox[\textwidth]{\framebox[2.5cm]{\rule{0pt}{2.5cm}}}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

An image of the output:

[image]

Could this be a problem with the `caption` and `floatrow` packages not working correctly together, as mentioned [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103361/subfloatrow-incorrect-continued-numbering), or am I doing something wrong? Is there a workaround?

Comment: Image uploaded :-)

Comment: Since the example works fine when using `caption` v3.2f I assume this is either the same or at least a related problem. The `floatrow` package seem to rely on the old internal behavior of the `caption` package. Until a fix is available I recommend downgrading to version 3.2f which you'll find here: https://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/code/69/tree/branches/3.2/tex/

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt Thank you very much for the quick reply and the suggested solution. Auf Wiedersehen!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thank you for adding the output picture. :-)

Comment: @JosephWright Will do right now...

Answer (score 3):

**Original Answer** (see comment above)

Since the example works fine when using `caption` v3.2f I assume this is either the same or at least a related problem. The `floatrow` package seem to rely on the old internal behavior of the `caption` package. Until a fix is available I recommend downgrading to version 3.2f which you'll find here: http://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/code/69/tree/branches/3.2/tex

**New Answer**

Yes, as suspected by the questioner it was the same problem as the one mentioned in [subfloatrow: incorrect continued numbering](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/103361/subfloatrow-incorrect-continued-numbering), and a fix is available since 2013-04-14.

See also: http://sourceforge.net/p/latex-caption/tickets/6/